# How do you display all the words that start with 1 uppercase letter using grep in bash?

Tags: bash, grep

I tried something like this
`sed 's/^[ \t]*//' file.txt | grep "^[A-Z].* "`
but it will show only the lines that start with words starting with an uppercase.

file.txt content:

Something1 something2
word1 Word2
this  is  lower

The output will be Something1 something2 but I will like for it to also show the second line because also has a word that starts with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU grep `grep -P "[A-Z]+\w*" file.txt` will work. Or, as @Shawn said in the comment below, `grep -P '\b[A-Z]' file.txt` will also work. If you only want the words, and not the entire line, `grep -Po "[A-Z]+\w*" file.txt` will give you the individual words.

Comment: There shouldn't be `\w*` at the beginning. That causes it to match words with capital letters anywhere, not just at the front.

Comment: `grep -P '\b[A-Z]' file.txt` is closer.

Comment: Both excellent points - I'll edit my answer

Comment: is there a way to omit words that include an uppercase letter in the middle of the word such as "invokeLater" also? thanks by the way it did the job I wanted to do mostly.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `grep`, you can use

```sh
grep '\<[[:upper:]]' file
grep '\b[[:upper:]]' file
```

**NOTE**:

- `\<` - a leading word boundary (`\b` is a word boundary)
- `[[:upper:]]` - any uppercase letter.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/NjytnI):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='Something1 something2  
word1 Word2  
this  is  lower
папа Петя'
grep '\<[[:upper:]]' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```sh
Something1 something2  
word1 Word2  
папа Петя
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do you display all the words

That's simple:

```
grep -wo '[A-Z]\w*'
```